# How to use Adobe AIR with Flex 4.6 SDK?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, mxml

I've been trying to use Adobe AIR 3.1 that comes with Flex 4.6 for my project.  I have been receiving the error `application descriptor not found`.

My descriptor file looks like this inside `D:/Test/`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- D:/Test/AIR.xml -->

<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
    <id>Test</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0</versionnumber>
    <filename>Main</filename>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>Main.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <width>800</width>
        <height>600</height>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

I build my swf with the following command while Main.mxml is in the /src subdirectory.

`D:/Flex/bin/mxmlc.exe -debug=true -swf-version=14 D:/Test/src/Main.mxml`

Then the SWF is moved to the /bin subdirectory.

I try using AIR with the following command in the directory `D:/Test/`.

`D:/Flex/bin/adl.exe AIR.xml /bin/`

My directory tree looks something like this:

```
D:/
- Flex/
-- bin/
--- adl.exe
- Test/
-- AIR.xml
-- bin/
--- Main.swf
-- src/
--- Main.mxml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't CamelCase the closing tag: `</versionnumber>`.  It is actually `</versionNumber>`.

Also, to run AIR, this is the proper command: `D:/Flex/bin/adl.exe AIR.xml`

And finally the content tags now hold this: `<content>bin/Main.swf</content>`